# Hyperledger Fabric version 1.2 multiple hosts deployment

Tags: deployment, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I've seen a few tutorials online that describes steps for Hyperledger Fabric  network multiple hosts deployment. All of the tutorials suggest to use docker swarm for the network deployment.

I wanted to know if using docker swarm is the Hyperledger Fabric multiple hosts deployment standard. Also, I wanted to know if there's a deployment standard for Hyperledger Fabric version 1.2 .

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Cello is a blockchain provision and operation system, which helps manage blockchain networks in an efficient way.

You can have a look at this : https://github.com/hyperledger/cello